How to recover missing files for emacs in /usr/bin?
I am trying to install emacs on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and when I use sudo apt-get install emacs I receive
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
emacs is already the newest version (1:29.3+1-1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

However, when I try to just run emacs from the terminal I get
bash: /usr/bin/emacs: No such file or directory

Any ideas how this can be fixed? I tried installing from source but I ran into lots of issues so I don't think I'm capable enough for that route.

What does 'type emacs' show ?

@SorenA emacs is hashed (/usr/bin/emacs)

AFAIK emacs is a metapackage - the actual program will be installed by one of its dependencies. What does update-alternatives --display emacs say?

@steeldriver update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for emacs

So do you have any other emacs packages installed (check with dpkg -l | grep emacs)? Or did you install emacs from completely outside of the Ubuntu package system (by building it from source for example)?

As @steeldriver mentioned, emacs is a metapackage.
If you are running X11, try
sudo apt install emacs-gtk
If you are running Wayland, try
sudo apt install emacs-pgtk
If you aren't sure if you are using X11 or Wayland, you can find out by typing
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
